# order by two columns with same priority

Tags: mysql

i have table , contain firstname and lastname ,

i used in my query :

> ORDER BY FNAME,LNAME ASC ,

It display the records alphabetical order , and it works fine for Fname,

but it is not giving the same periority to LNAME,

my present table records :

```
No Fname Lname
1   Agh   Asd
2   Arh   AAA
3   Bcvc  Vvcv
4   Akasa Dvxvx
```

After my query:: ORDER BY FNAME,LNAME ASC ,

```
No Fname Lname
1   Agh   Asd
4   Akasa Dvxvx
2   Arh   AAA
3   Bcvc  Vvcv
```

But what How i want is

```
No Fname Lname
1   Agh   Asd
2   Arh   AAA
4   Akasa Dvxvx
3   Bcvc  Vvcv
```

Yes if i change the order by lname,fname asc , then i get the expected output,

But since query giveing the high priority to the first field in the order by ,

How to over ride this,

i want equal priority in my query ,

Any good suggestion

Comment: So if you know how to get what you want, what is the problem?  You cannot sort two fields with "equal" priority.  One has to be done first.

Comment: You don't want equal priority in sorting, you just want to sort by `Lname` first and `Fname` second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is **equal** priority? What comes first: 'Aaa Zzz' or 'Zzz Aaa' and where comes 'Mmm Mmm' between the both?

Do you want to `ORDER BY` the first letters of both `fname` and `lname`, then by the second, etc.?

```
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(lname, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(fname, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(lname, 2, 1), SUBSTRING(fname, 2, 1)
```